# Hour difference in PHP

Tags: php

How to calculate the difference in hours and minutes? In my code below,

```
echo $d = ((strtotime("18:00:00") - strtotime("17:30:00"))/60)/60;

Actual Result: 0.5  
Expected Result: 0.30

echo $d = ((strtotime("19:00:00") - strtotime("17:30:00"))/60)/60;

Actual Result: 1.5  
Expected Result: 1.30
```

How can do this?

Comment: `$d = strtotime("18:00:00") - strtotime("17:30:00");
echo ($d/60)."  minutes";`

Comment: it works... But if i use  $d = strtotime("19:00:00") - strtotime("17:30:00"); echo ($d/60)." minutes";   can we get result should be 2.30 ??

Comment: That's why i add some description in my answer.

Comment: Do you need this feature??

Comment: Yes. Now i am getting "1.5" answer.  But it should be "1.30"

Comment: Okey, i will update my answer with in some time.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Check my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide the difference by 60. As you just need Min, If you want to format it validly then need some more formation. But this is valid only for Difference of Min.

```
$d = strtotime("18:00:00") - strtotime("17:30:00"); echo ($d/60)." minutes";
```

**result:** 30  minutes

SO you want to get the difference like `1.30`. Try this:

```
$d = strtotime("18:00:00") - strtotime("16:40:00");
$d = $d/60;

if($d > 59){
    $m = $d%60;
    $d = intval($d/60); 
    echo $d.".".$m;
}else
    echo $d. " Miniutes";
```

Comment: Both answer are wroking fine. but i thought Thamilan's answer is an one line code...

Comment: if you think his answer is fine than you must go with him.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
echo $d = round((strtotime("18:00:00") - strtotime("17:30:00"))/60, 1);
```

Dividing by 60 since you need to convert to minutes
Using round() to restrict to one decimal point.

---

**Edit:** (Answered after question is updated)

You can use [gmdate](https://www.php.net/gmdate) function:

```
$d = strtotime("19:00:00") - strtotime("17:30:00");

echo gmdate("G.i", $d);
```

Used `G` instead of `H` since you need hour without leading zero.

Result:

```
1.30
```

Comment: I need hour and minute format. the result is "1.5". But i need "1.30"

Comment: @selvan Updated the answer